# How to check history in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table `tbpayment` with 5 columns:

1. StudentId  //payer
2. Amount
3. Datepay
4. Status//paid or notpaid.
5. AdminID//reciever or who manages data.

Admin refers to AdminId.

Admin can change payer status to paid or notpaid. But I didn't control this issue.

Ex: first, Admin does paid for payer and after that he changes payer status to notpaid to make problem. This can work through Update statement and after update data is replaced. MultiAdmin.

I want to know that:

Can I view history of this payer in SQL log or cannot?

And possible to know who is the Admin on each time?

And how to check the history?

Comment: you need a trigger on that table, which, when update happens, write information about this update invocation into another history table. in trigger, while it is executing you can get all values of old state of row, all values of new state of row and database user who is executing update via sql functions such as session_user() etc. search for "tsql triggers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I view history of this payer in SQL log or cannot

No, this wouldn't be logged to the SQL Server error log by default

> And possible to know who is the Admin on each time? And how to check
>   the history?

Sure, but it is going to take some configuring on your end. Essentially you are wanting to audit or log changes made to this table. For this, you have a few options.

1. Manually audit the changes by creating an [`AFTER INSERT / UPDATE TRIGGER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) which logs the entire row to an audit table. This will allow you to see all *versions* of any columns you specify
2. Set up a [SQL Server audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine) to do this for you
3. Set up [`rowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to capture the changes
4. Set up [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) to capture the changes

All of these have their pro's and cons, and levels of complication. The easiest route would be a trigger to an audit table, since you can customize it to your liking rather quickly.